# Finding the count of metal spheres in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I need to count the number of metal balls inside a small metal cup.
I tried template matching but it showed only one result having most probability.
But i need the count of total metal balls visible.
Since background too is metallic i was unable to do color thresholding.
I tried a method of finding the first occurrence using template matching and then fill that area with RGB(0,0,0) and again did the template matching on that image, but several false detections are occurring.
My primary requirement is to find the images that have three balls filled inside the cup and any other quantities other than three should not be detected.

Please see the [images](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5EF81FCE197CFB9C!443) of different quantities filled inside the cup

Comment: How did  you resolve issue with template matching triangles finding them in both images with 3 balls and with 4 balls? Or did you manage to get watershed to work  Just a bit curious about the accepted answer, when circle matching is proven to work.

Comment: I tried the method of template matching of middle triangle. And it surely worked out. Now have to get rotated inputs too. Also combined it with hough circle after some thresholding taking advantage of lighting and then did some morphological transfomation to remove some noice

Comment: Complete ougput is not yet obtained. Will sure share after that

Comment: But when triangle is detected with images with three balls and with four balls, how to tell the difference?

Comment: That time hough circle will give four output right. If triangle is matched it can be short listed to three balls or four balls right. Then hough circle output will be done and if both matches it is accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Hough circles - see the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) for how to do this. Then just count the circles that are with some empirically determined radius range.

Here are some results and code that will enable you to do what you want:

[image: All balls identified by HoughCircles]

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool circle_compare (Vec3f i,Vec3f j) { return (i[2]>j[2]); }


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    /// Read the image
    Mat one = imread("one.jpg", 1 );
    Mat two = imread("two.jpg", 1 );
    Mat three = imread("three.jpg", 1 );
    Mat four = imread("four.jpg", 1 );
    if(!one.data  || !two.data  || !three.data  || !four.data)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // put all the images into one
    Mat src(one.rows * 2, one.cols * 2, one.type());
    Rect roi1(0, 0, one.cols, one.rows);
    one.copyTo(src(roi1));
    Rect roi2(one.cols, 0, one.cols, one.rows);
    two.copyTo(src(roi2));
    Rect roi3(0, one.rows, one.cols, one.rows);
    three.copyTo(src(roi3));
    Rect roi4(one.cols, one.rows, one.cols, one.rows);
    four.copyTo(src(roi4));

    // extract the blue channel because the circles show up better there
    vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(src, channels);
    cv::Mat blue;
    GaussianBlur( channels[0], blue, Size(7, 7), 4, 4 );

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    vector<Vec3f> candidate_circles;

    /// Find the circles
    HoughCircles( blue, candidate_circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 30, 55);//, 0, 200 );

    // sort candidate cirles by size, largest first
    // so the accepted circles are the largest that meet other criteria
    std::sort (candidate_circles.begin(), candidate_circles.end(), circle_compare);

    /// Draw the circles detected
    for( size_t i = 0; i < candidate_circles.size(); ++i )
    {
        Point center(cvRound(candidate_circles[i][0]), cvRound(candidate_circles[i][4]));
        int radius = cvRound(candidate_circles[i][5]);

        // skip over big circles
        if(radius > 35)
            continue;

        // test whether centre of candidate_circle is inside of accepted circle
        bool inside = false;
        for( size_t j = 0; j < circles.size(); ++j )
        {
            Point c(cvRound(circles[j][0]), cvRound(circles[j][6]));
            int r = cvRound(circles[j][7]);

            int d = sqrt((center.x - c.x) * (center.x - c.x) + (center.y - c.y) * (center.y - c.y));

            if(d <= r)
            {
                inside = true; // candidate is inside an existing circle
            }
        }
        if(inside)
            continue;

        // accept the current candidate circle then draw it
        circles.push_back(candidate_circles[i]);
        circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
        circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
    }

    // now fill the circles in the quadrant that has three balls 
    vector<Vec3f> tl, tr, bl, br;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); ++i )
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][8]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][9]);

        if(center.x < one.cols)
        {
            if(center.y < one.rows)
            {
                tl.push_back(circles[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                bl.push_back(circles[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(center.y < one.rows)
            {
                tr.push_back(circles[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                br.push_back(circles[i]);
            }
        }

        vector<vector<Vec3f>> all;
        all.push_back(tl);
        all.push_back(tr);
        all.push_back(bl);
        all.push_back(bl);
        for( size_t k = 0; k < all.size(); ++k )
        {
            if(all[k].size() == 3)
            {
                for( size_t i = 0; i < all[k].size(); ++i )
                {
                    Point center(cvRound(all[k][i][0]), cvRound(all[k][i][10]));
                    int radius = cvRound(all[k][i][11]);
                    circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,255, 255), -1, 4, 0 );
                }
            }
        }  
    }

    // resize for easier display
    resize(src, src, one.size());

    /// Save results and display them 
    imwrite("balls.png", src);
    //namedWindow( "Balls", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Balls", src );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the images may be too poor for this to work reliably.

Comment: But hough circle is giving lot of false detections

Comment: @Able Eldhose false detections are partly due to incorrect parameter choices. It easy to eliminate the circles you don't want. See the code I have added to my post. The case of four balls is difficult, perhaps you have some ideas to fix it?

Comment: Did this not solve your problem? I found the right number of balls in every image and filled them in for the image with three balls.

Comment: Some mismatches are occuring may be my fault. Iam trying to combine both test for a confirmation. False detection cant be tolerated because its used in a production line and incorrect detection will reject that product. Iam using the code you provided and am trying to combine the triangle detection for further confirmation. Please correct me if iam going in wrong way. Iam a novice in opencv

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the template matching algorithm, but with a twist. Don't look for circles (balls). But look for the small triangle in center of the 3 balls.

You have to take into account the rotation of the triangle, but simple contour processing should do the job.

1. define ROI in center of the image (center of cup)
2. run some edge detector and contour detection
3. simplify every suitable contour found
4. check if found contour has 3 corners with angle sharp enough to form an triangle

To distinguish case with more than 3 balls check also overall intensity of the image. Photo of 3 balls only should have quite low intensity compared to one with more balls.

EDIT:
2013-11-08 6.15PM GMT

In this case of image, might be actually helpfull to use watershed segmentation algorithm.

This algorithm is part of OpenCV, I don't now which version is the first one, but it seems it's in OCV 3.0.0: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=watershed#cv2.watershed

Some basic for watershed on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_%28image_processing%29

Comment: This is a good idea worth trying, but after edge detection the triangle is quite "wiggly" so it might be difficult to get going.

Comment: I too think this is a good ideaWill surely try this and get back

Comment: I've added another idea for solving this problem, see attached links.

Comment: I think using watershed for this is difficult (correct me if I am wrong). The problem is setting appropriate markers. The easiest thing to do would be to look for the specular reflections on the balls, but some balls have two.